# Why does my regex do this?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Consider the following text:

```
foo:·····¶
·bar x··¶
·lorem ipsum····¶
dolorsitamet···¶
···¶   
consectetur adipiscing elit:
```

Where middle dots indicate spaces and `¶` indicates a newline.

The regex `(?:foo:\s*)(.+)(?:\n\s*)` matches the three spaces on the whitespace line, but the regex `(?:foo:\s*)(.+)(?:\n\s+)` matches up to and not including the newline following `dolorsitamet`. Why does the * character not behave greedily? One would expect the third group `(?:\n\s*)` to match

```
¶
···¶`
```

My regex mode is multiline, dotall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greedy nature is not the problem here. Issues is when you use:

```
\n\s*
```

And since `.+` before this is greedy, `\n\s*` matches very last `\n` in input text i.e. `(last-1)th` line (i.e. line with 3 space) and stops.

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/gJ7cQ6/2)

However, when you use

```
\n\s+
```

Due to presence of quantifier `+`, it requires **at least one whitespace after `\n`** hence it cannot match `\n` in `(last-1)th` line (since last line doesn't have any whitespace at start). Hence it matches `\n` in the line starting with `dolorsitamet` as next line has white-spaces at start.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/gJ7cQ6/1)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Regex101 to craft the regex.  What I actually want is for it to match everything between `foo:·····¶` and the whitespace after `dolorsitamet···` (I don't care about trailing whitespace, but no newline), but it should also return what it currently does for the text here 
https://regex101.com/r/jZ5hU0/1. 

What would be the correct way to match it?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution to be 
`(?:foo:\s*)(.+?)((?:$)|(?:\n\ +\n))`

Comment: A bit simplified: `(?:foo:\s*)(.+?)(\n\s+\n|$)`

Answer (score 1):

It does behave greedily. However, in order to match `\n\s+` at the end, it needs to match a newline character followed by at least one whitespace character. In this case, that's the next-to-last newline, the three spaces, and the last newline.

If it doesn't stop there, the `.+` will capture more, but the last part won't match and the regex engine will look for a less-greedy solution, which is what it finds.